# C#, WPF - Animate item removed from listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

Got this XAML code animating when adding an item to my listbox - works great:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:2">
                            </DoubleAnimation>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Is there anyway I can do the same when removing an item in my listbox?

I have an:

```
ObservableCollection<string> _data = new ObservableCollection<string>();
```

which stores the items.

EDIT: Problems seems to be, that when I am removing it from the ObservableCollection the item is removed first, then animation is run - but nothing displays because the item isn't there anymore? Am I right?

Best regards

Answer (score -1):

Please try to write another `EventTrigger` with `RoutedEvent` set to `FrameworkElement.Unloaded` and inside provide you `Storyboard`

Comment: Tried that. It won't work because the item is deleted before the animation can happen. Let's say I make a class for my ObservableCollection with a property bool "GonnaBeDeleted". Then I could set it to true for the item I would like to delete, then animation should happen first and then delete. But how do I "listen" for changes when I update an items property GonnaBeDeleted to true? So the trigger will happen?

Comment: If you're using MVVM, it's simple. Create a property and in setter write: `NotifyPropertyChanged("NameOfYourProperty)`.

If you're not using MVVM, let's try to implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface in code behind, and:

`public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;`

`public void HandlePropertyChanged(string prop)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }`

and in setter you can write then: `HandlePropertyChanged("NameOfYourProperty")`